# Adjusting the sidebar when scrolling with the mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item active" data-target="block1"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-dot"></i></li>
                <li class="menu-item" data-target="block2"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle"></i></li>
                <li class="menu-item" data-target="block3"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle"></i></li>
                <li class="menu-item" data-target="block4"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle"></i></li>
                <li class="menu-item" data-target="block5"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
}

.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .menu-item {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .content {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const target = this.dataset.target;
    const targetBlock = document.getElementById(target);
    const targetBlockOffsetTop = targetBlock.offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo({
      top: targetBlockOffsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    updateActiveIcon(item);
  });
});

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  const direction = event.deltaY > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
  const activeIndex = getActiveBlockIndex();
  let targetIndex;

  if (direction === 'down' && activeIndex < blocks.length - 1) {
    targetIndex = activeIndex + 1;
  } else if (direction === 'up' && activeIndex > 0) {
    targetIndex = activeIndex - 1;
  }

  if (targetIndex !== undefined) {
    const targetBlock = blocks[targetIndex];
    const targetBlockOffsetTop = targetBlock.offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo({
      top: targetBlockOffsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    updateActiveIcon(menuItems[targetIndex]);
  }
});

function getActiveBlockIndex() {
  let activeIndex = -1;

  blocks.forEach(function(block, index) {
    const blockOffsetTop = block.offsetTop;
    const blockHeight = block.offsetHeight;
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

    if (scrollTop >= blockOffsetTop && scrollTop < blockOffsetTop + blockHeight) {
      activeIndex = index;
    }
  });

  return activeIndex;
}

function updateActiveIcon(activeItem) {
  menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
item.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle"></i>';
});

activeItem.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-dot"></i>';
}
```

The site has a sidebar, I want to set it up to change icons for display for a better understanding of the user where he is now on the site. Sidebar now responds well to user clicks, the icon changes depending on the selected item, but does not respond at all if the user scrolls.

The site consists of 5 blocks, each block is 937 pixels high, now the function is also configured, scrolling the site page immediately to the whole screen, the standard sidebar of the browser is also disabled.

Comment: _"The site consists of [...]"_ - please present a proper [mre] of that then, so that not everyone who wants to test/verify the issue, has to create that "environment" themselves.